# Word that means "outdated name"

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there a word that means "outdated name"?
For example:

- *Record*, although very little music is on vinyl
- *Film*, although most movies are digital
- *Horsepower*, although no one uses horses as a metric anymore
- *Phone*, although it's mostly used to access the web

and so on.

Comment: How about 'old fashioned'? +1

Comment: Also, "sail" across the sea and "dial" a number.

Comment: Anyone think of anymore? Could be interesting to list them here in the comments.

Comment: Is the term "horsepower" really outdated if it's a standard measurement unit?  It doesn't fall into the same category of archaic measurement unit that "fortnight" would.

Comment: This isn't relevant to the question, but I don't think I would say "most" movies are digital yet, although it's headed that way. Lots of movies are still shot on film, and most are still projected from film.

Comment: @MatthewCrumley: It depends on where you live.  In the US, it is difficult to find theaters showing any movies on film.

Comment: @Gnubie A few years back some radio talk show host noted that "dial" doesn't really make sense as we no longer actually dial phones, and so he announced a contest for people to send in new words or phrases. A week later he announced the winning entry: "digitally initiate audio link". Of course that's a long and cumbersome phrase, but the sumibtter suggested that for everyday use people could use the acronym: DIAL.

Comment: @oosterwal The poster isn't saying that these words are no longer used, but rather that they are "outdated" in the sense that their literal meaning or roots are no longer applicable. As I think about this now I'd quibble. "Film": yes, as movies become digital, this is anachronistic. But there's no such issue with his other examples. "Phone" is short for "telephone" which comes from the Greek for "far sound". That word implies nothing about whether the sound is transmitted digitally over the Internet or by analog signals over traditional phone wires. "Horsepower" measures power ...

Comment: ... in comparison to what a "standard draft horse" can produce. It doesn't imply that the power is actually being produced by horses. Quite the contrary, it was invented when steam engines came along precisely to give a way to measure power NOT produced by horses. When people really did use horses, they didn't say, "This is a 4 horsepower wagon", they said, "This wagon is pulled by 4 horses." And I don't think I've ever heard someone call a CD or MP3 download a "record", so I think that's a moot point.

Comment: @Jay:  Agreed.  In that case I offer "roll", as in "roll up the window."  There are plenty of cars that still use the hand cranks, but powered windows seem to be the norm these days.

Comment: @Jay: For the *phone* example, the OP notes that today's phones are typically **not** used for transmitting sound, but rather for browsing the Web. Fewer and fewer people even have land-line phones anymore, and "smartphones" are basically small computers more than they are portable telephones.

Comment: @JohnY Well, okay, to the extent that you use your phone as a web browser, it's not really a "phone". Personally I used the browser feature on my phone about twice, so I guess I missed the point he was trying to make.

Comment: This is reminiscent of the whole floppy disc for save icon gui argument that went down recently (e.g. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheFloppyDiskMeansSaveAnd14OtherOldPeopleIconsThatDontMakeSenseAnymore.aspx).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

These terms are *holdovers* from a previous era.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. I'd go so far as to say that these are _linguistic holdovers_, in that it's not so much the technology or the medium that survived, but the words that persisted. (One of my favorites is _glove compartment_. Every now and then, I've heard people refer to the refrigerator as an _icebox_, too. Funny how they still call those things you get at a hotel a [key](http://www.cardjett.com/store/pc/viewPrd.asp?idproduct=48&IDCategory=15). Okay, I'll get off my [soapbox](http://farm1.static.flickr.com/72/218553500_b2ee528066.jpg) now...)

Comment: This is a better choice than *anachronism* (see also comments at @JLG's answer).

Answer (score 15):

You could say that it's an *anachronism*.

Comment: An anachronism is something out of its own time, e.g. a television in Victorian London, or people using muskets in a space battle.

Comment: -1 As @Ben notes, an *anachronism* is something in the wrong time period (like everything in the Flinstones) which is not what the OP is describing.

Comment: @Ben, Dave. But a full-rigged ship today would definitely be a tangible anachronism: I don't think OPs context is too much of a stretch.

Answer (score 11):

Such expressions are perhaps edging towards *fossilised metaphor*.

Comment: Is that the same as a 'dead metaphor' (a non-literal usage which is not recognized as a metaphor at all)

Comment: @Mitch: I believe so.

Comment: But his examples aren't metaphors. They may be fossilized something-else.

Comment: @Jay: I did say 'edging towards'.

Comment: I can't find any instances of 'fossilised metaphor' (British spelling) and rare use of 'fossilized metaphor' and 'fossil metaphor' [via ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fossilized+metaphor%2Cfossilised+metaphor%2Cfossil+metaphor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Answer (score 10):

[*Archaism* is defined as](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/archaism): An archaic word, phrase, idiom, or other expression.

And [*archaic*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/archaic) itself has a linguistics-related definition (see #3 below)

> **archaic** [ɑːˈkeɪɪk]
>   adj
>   1. belonging to or characteristic of a much earlier period; ancient
>   2. out of date; antiquated an archaic prison system
>   3. (*Linguistics*) (of idiom, vocabulary, etc.) characteristic of an earlier period of a language and not in ordinary use

Comment: Archaic words are those words which are **`no longer in everyday use but sometimes used to impart an old-fashioned flavor`**.

Comment: @rudra, You could argue that the words in the OP's question belong to an earlier period and are out of date (using my definition).

Comment: OP is looking for a term for words in current use; the definition cited in this answer clearly identifies "archaic" as a term for words *not* in current use.

Comment: +1 I think this word can be used in some colloquial context to emphatize the old-fashiond usage of some terms.

Comment: I don't think [*anachronism*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/anachronism) is quite right, either, though, based on its definition. I personally voted for *holdover.*

Comment: I think anachronism is simply **wrong**.

Comment: I suggest a neologism (or should I say *neologue*): *Anachronym*. My favorite is *turn on*. Why do we *turn on* a light or other appliance by flipping up a switch if not because the name harks back to the time when oil or gas lamps (and many other devices) turned on and off by means of a knob or wing nut to open or close a valve or potentiometer?

Comment: @HStephenStraight, see chaos' answer where he suggests just that word.

Comment: This is the correct and best answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best possible word for this is **anachronym**.

Comment: Did you just make that word up or are you refering to *anacronym*?

Comment: Right: an _anacronym_ is an acronym that most people use as a word, without knowing the original words whose initials make it up, like "laser" or "radar".

Comment: Made up the same word. Really like it. Will probably use it.

Answer (score 3):

> Antiquated

is probably a good fit (antiquated terms/terminology):

> an·ti·quat·ed/ˈantiˌkwātid/Adjective: Old-fashioned or outdated.
>   Synonyms: obsolete - out-of-date - old-fashioned - outdated

or

> outmoded

.

Comment: Where are those citations from? Please tell us the name of where you got those from, and if applicable, also a link. If you are going copy out text verbatim, [our Help Center says that you must name](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) where you got the original from, and this post fails to do that. Please see the question on meta entitled [“What to do about missing source attributions: Copying, Linking, Attributions, and Plagiarism](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/4973) for discussion on this.

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated? Although it sounds like you want a noun.

Comment: Do you mean depreciated - or do you really disaprove of the terms? :)

Comment: @Wolf5370  — Deprecated is a computer programming term used for e.g. some function in a language that can still be used but is discouraged because something better has been provided. Generally there is a threat that the deprecated function will be withdrawn at some later stage. See, e.g. this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning) — It's not a very good answer in my opinion, but that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

They're perhaps "stabilized" or "commemorative" metaphors more than "fossilized" ones in that nothing better has come along.

Their common appeal is that they have a sense of immediacy and tactile quality to them: the hand on the phone set to dial, the glove in the compartment, the ship gliding on the sea - even film (over video) has a sensuous quality - its thinness, the image of a film of oil floating on water comes to mind.