# Is there a term for coining a phrase for a word that already exists?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, terminology, neologisms

Usually a new term emerges and it becomes necessary to add a qualification to an old word for disambiguation.

> examples:
>
> - "mono sound" versus "stereo sound"
> - "analog watch" versus "digital watch"
> - "acoustic guitar" versus "electric guitar"
> - "slow food" versus "fast food"

Comment: If any string becomes rather more commonly used than would be expected (eg 'happy bunny' but not 'happy puppy') it is called a _collocation_. Modifier + noun is a common type. If the term becomes fossilised into a multiword lexeme, it is called a _compound_. It may go on to become hyphenated and/or solid in form. The process is known as _compounding_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have named textbook cases of the ***[retronym](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=retronym)***, which AHD defines as

> A word or phrase created because an existing term that was once used alone needs to be distinguished from a term referring to a new development, as *acoustic guitar* in contrast to *electric guitar* or *analog watch* in contrast to *digital watch*.

[Language Log and others ascribe the term](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=15399) ca. 1980 to Frank Mankiewicz, a writer and Democratic political strategist who was later head of National Public Radio. You can find a large collection of them at [Retronyms.org](http://www.retronyms.org/).

For a related phenomenon, see *[Word that means “outdated name”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72520)*.

Comment: good link. I especially like "we can soon expect all signs to read: "Keep off the natural turf.""

Comment: I can see this question/answer going viral! I don't know if I'd come across the word before. The meaning is so obvious in any likely context that you'd hardly need to *remember* it for the purpose of comprehension, but it could be really useful if you were able to *reproduce* it. In the ever-increasing number of contexts where you want to refute someone else's pointing out that some two-word pairing is tautological (because it *was* once, but things have moved on).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Nah. The question hasn't hit the [network-wide superconducting multicollider](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/5306) (NWSCMC), and the answer isn't [joke-related](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152704). Besides, the inclusion of references and the omission of obvious typographical errors dooms it to languish in non-celebrity by the Stack Exchange Law of Unrequited Rigor.

Comment: Well, if it never hits the multicollider, the best comparison might be with [skeuomorph](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/57184/2637) - which has only 16 upvotes after 2.5 years, but was well & truly burninated into *my* memory when I first saw it there. This one seems at least as useful, so I bet in 2.5 years from now, it'll have more than that! And unless I go totally [doolally](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/174321/2637) in the meantime, I'll still remember it (since I want to be able to *use* it as well as *recognize* it). Good word, thanks!

Comment: @FF I've come here as a result of a dupesearch. I was about to upvote when I realised I already had.